# keyboardWillShowNotification edge case

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit, nsnotificationcenter

This is a problem of order of operations

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];    
[nc addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
           name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
         object:nil];
[nc addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
         object:nil];
```

And then I add a textbox to a UITableViewCell:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldBegin:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];

[cell addSubview:textField];
```

In textFieldBegin, I scrollToRowAtIndexPath to move to the cell being edited.
In keyboardWillShow I adjust the frame of the tableView to allow for the keyboard.
**textFieldBegin** gets called *before* **keyboardWillShow**, so the first time it is shown it has no room to scroll.

Is there an elequent way to fix this oversight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the current scroll position in a variable during begin, then in the keyboardwillshow notification you could re-scroll to whatever position is stored in that variable.

I think that would allow you to keep your different animations where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` you can react to the UITextFieldDelegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and resize/scroll in that method, since it is called *after* the keyboard is shown.

Comment: Since iOS 4.0 (I think), that is no longer true. In iOS 3.0, I think textFieldDidBeginEditing: only happened *after* the keyboard fully appeared, which looks silly.